# Is there a driver for canoscan D646U scanner?

Tags: drivers

Is there a driver for CanoScan D646U scanner? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and can't get my scanner to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to Canon:

> There is no driver for the OS Version you selected. The driver may be
>   included in your OS or you may not need a driver.

Also you can checkout the [Sane Project](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON), that also shows that the scanner is not supported.